# when create a managed bean annotation i have a bug (the attribut name is undefined for the annotation type ManagedBean)

Tags: jsf, managed-bean

Code:

`@ManagedBean(name="userbean")`

Error message

> the attribute name is undefined for the annotation type ManagedBean

Comment: Wrong suggestion. Most likely the import is of the wrong type.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have imported the wrong type.

Try:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
@ManagedBean
public class UserBean...{}
```

and when using so use 
     `#{userBean.action()}`

Comment: and for exemple when i use the ManagedBean in Form i write:

Comment: <table> 
    
    <tr>
     <td>Nom:</td>
     <td><h:inputText value="#{userBean.action().nom}" required="true" 
    
       id="nom" /> <h:message for="nom" /></td>
    </tr>

Comment: Wrong suggestion. Most likely the import is of the wrong type